# How to setup phpmyadmin's designer tab on wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I have searched the net, watched youtube videos and to no avail. I'm looking to get the designer tab on phpmyadmin where I would be able to see table relations like you would in ms Access. I have set my config.inc.php exactly like I have seen on countless sites, run the sql to create the phpmyadmin db and I'm just not getting the tab for designer view.

I have used `config.sample.inc.php` file and uncommented  all these lines:

```
/* User used to manipulate with storage */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';

/* Storage database and tables */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
```

Then save the file over config.inc.php, login and recieve this error.

**"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."**

Clicking "here' takes me to this page which I'm guessing is basically telling me everything is disabled

[image]

This is what I'm after. It must be able to be done. I'm clearly missing something

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP needed to be restarted. And you will only see the designer tab on the db page not on the table page. Otherwise everything I did according to this YouTube video worked

http://youtu.be/hPYLbaXa35o

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does apache need to be restarted? I am coming across the same problem only with a linux server. (I have to wait until the sysadmin can restart apache)

Comment: I'm not sure, but once apache was restarted, it then worked. I was only using it for local dev, to make writing large sql joins easier for me. Once I had it on the live server, I had no need for it. I think because you edit a config file, apache will only re-cache the file on a restart. Thats what I beleive. I could be wrong